# web scraping - webdriver in for loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website: [https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=2060160&q=%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EA%B4%80&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=2&csq={panre_bub_idx:%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EC%9B%90}&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=01&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm=%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EC%9B%90](https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=2060160&q=%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EA%B4%80&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=2&csq=%7Bpanre_bub_idx:%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EC%9B%90%7D&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=01&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm=%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EC%9B%90)

It has two buttons at the very top left of the page `<이전글` (previous item) and `다음글` (next item). The url above shows the very first item, hence clicking on `<이전글`(previous item) simply refreshes the same page.

I am trying to scrape the content in the right box of each of the pages, until I reach the very last item (i.e. until clicking on  `다음글` (next item) would only refresh the same page).

From inspecting the page, if the item is the very last item, then the `a[href]` of the button `다음글` (next item) is simply `"#//`, while for all previous items their `a[href]`s of the button `다음글` (next item) are the url for the next item.

I want to use a for loop somehow (maybe I am wrong and there are other more efficient ways of approaching this), but I've been struggling to write the right logic for it. This is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import re
from tqdm import tqdm


def get_content(wd, url, lst): 
  wd.get(url)

  html = wd.page_source
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

  for i in soup.find("div", {"class:", "con_area_02"}).find_all(["h2","p"]):
    lst.append(i.text)
  
  url = soup.find("div", {"class:", "tit_area"}).find_all("a")[-1]['href']
  return url


# url of the very first item
url = "https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=2060160&q=%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EA%B4%80&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=2&csq={panre_bub_idx:%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EC%9B%90}&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=01&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm=%EB%8C%80%EB%B2%95%EC%9B%90" 

sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36")

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
l = []

while get_content(wd, url, l) != "#//": # logic seems off here
  get_content(wd, url, l)
  url = get_content(wd, url, l)

  #print(len(l))
```

Thank you!

---

EDIT: My edited code is as below, but the urls that get printed out from the print statement tend to be duplicated as time goes by (they are printed twice or more).

Without the `time.sleep()`,  I get an error pretty much immediately after the same url gets printed for almost 10 times.

Am I missing something?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
import time


sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36")

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

start_url = "https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=3225630&q=*&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=1&csq=&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=20000101~20201231&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=01&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm="
content_l = []


def scrape(webdriver, url, l):
  time.sleep(4)
  wd.get(url)
  html = wd.page_source
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

  for i in soup.find("div", {"class:", "con_area_02"}).find_all(["h2","p"]):
    l.append(i.text)
  
  next_btn = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="다음글"]')

  if str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")) != "#//":
    print(str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")))
    return scrape(webdriver, str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")), l)
  elif str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")) == "#//":
    return l 


scrape(wd, start_url, content_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
next_btn = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[name="btnContNext"]')
while next_btn.get_attribute("href") != "#//":
    #do your scraping
    .............
    next_btn.click()
    time.sleep(4) #make the next page loaded
    next_btn = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[name="btnContNext"]') #fetch the next button again
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: No it didn't :( I have edited my question to update what I have tried recently - I'd be grateful if you could have a look and advise. Thanks!

Comment: I'm now also getting the following error: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". Is recursion something that shouldn't normally be used for web-scraping?

Comment: Well, when you coming back almost after a month... Try asking this again so other users will see this question too, maybe someone will be able to help here.